# send html file and data using express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to send a html file and an object to the client from server using express such that when the file gets loaded it uses the object and structure dynamically using ajax.

I know that the html file can be send like this:

```
res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "main.html" )
```

object as:

```
res.json(obj);
```

But how to send them together?

Comment: This might not exactly answer your question, but it's good tool I used for the same purpose. Check it out: [ejs](http://ejs.co/). It's a templating engine for html that works with node.js Here is the npm module: [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs)

Comment: @StefanOctavian Thanks for the info. But this will not serve my purpose.

Comment: See my answer and tell me if it helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple word, you can not send json and html together as we need to send `content-type` in header. You can either send html or json.

Another way, you can send html into josn with other object something like following

```
const fs = require('fs');

const html = fs.readFileSync( __dirname + '/main.html' );
res.json({html: html.toString(), data: obj});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways you can do that. While not the best method, this is the one I used in my projects. I used ejs, a powerful and simple templating engine.

First, install it using npm

```
npm install ejs
```

Then, in your HTML add:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var obj = JSON.parse(<%= objSentFromServer %>)
   // do something with obj
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Server Side:

```
let express = require('express')
let app = express()
let ejs = require('ejs')
let fs = require('fs')
let objectSentFromServer = ... // what you need to send

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/main.html', (err, html) => {
    res.send(ejs.render(html, JSON.stringify(objectSentFromServer)))
  })
})

app.listen(8080, (err) => { console.log(err) })
```

Of course, there are plenty of other ways.

Answer (score 0):

You may not be able to achieve this by sending back plain HTML.
But you should be able to achieve this using a templating engine. With the help of templating engine, you should be able to render a view as well as pass JSON required to used in that template.

Reference: [render view](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.render)

Eg;

```
// pass a local variable to the view
res.render('user', { name: 'Tobi' }, function(err, html) {
  // ...
});
```

Here is the complete list of [Template Engines](https://github.com/expressjs/express/wiki#template-engines) supported by Express JS